# When restoring data from JSON into WPF the DisplayMemberPath is blank

Tags: c#, json, wpf, restore

I have a DataGridComboBox and both the ItemsSource and SelectedItemBinding are binding correctly.

XAML:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding BicnList}" x:Key="bicnList"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DgNamingConventionRows}"
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bicnList}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding BuiltInCategoryName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                     <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"/>
                     </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <!--............!-->
           </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
     </Grid>
```

When opening the combobox all options are displayed correctly and when I select an item I can also see the `DisplayMemberPath` correctly.

[image]

I'm saving this data using json and this is also correctly done.

[image]

However, after closing the window, I want to restore this data when opening again the WPF. The data is restored and deserialization is working properly, but there is no display under the Category Combobox. The DisplayMemberPath is blank. What could be the cause of this issue? Any help would be appretiated.

[image]

C#:

```cs
    private ObservableCollection<BuiltInCategoryName> _bicnList = new
                ObservableCollection<BuiltInCategoryName>();
            
            [JsonIgnore]
            public ObservableCollection<BuiltInCategoryName> BicnList
            {
                get
                {
                    return _bicnList;
                }
                set
                {
                    _bicnList = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("BicnList");
                }
            }
```

```cs
    public class BuiltInCategoryName : NotifierBase
    {
        //display Category.Name
        //save BuiltInCategory.Id
     
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
     
        public BuiltInCategory BuiltInCategoryId { get; set; }
     
        public BuiltInCategoryName(Document doc, BuiltInCategory bic)
        {
            Category cat = null;
            try
            {
                cat = Category.GetCategory(doc, bic);
            }
            catch
            { }
            CategoryName = cat?.Name;
            BuiltInCategoryId = bic;
        }
        public BuiltInCategoryName()
        {
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class ParameterRow : NotifierBase
        {
            private BuiltInCategoryName builtInCategoryName ;
            public BuiltInCategoryName BuiltInCategoryName 
            {
                get { return builtInCategoryName ; }
                set
                {
                    SetNotify(ref builtInCategoryName , value);
                }
            }
     
            private string patternText;
            public string PatternText
            {
                get { return patternText; }
                set
                {
                    SetNotify(ref patternText, value);
                }
            }
     
            private string comparisonValue;
            public string ComparisonValue
            {
                get { return comparisonValue; }
                set
                {
                    SetNotify(ref comparisonValue, value);
                }
            }
     
            public ParameterRow(BuiltInCategoryName category, string patternText, string comparison)
            {
                BuiltInCategoryName = category;
                PatternText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(patternText) ? "" : patternText;
                ComparisonValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(patternText) ? "Prefix" : comparison;
            }
            public ParameterRow()
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a deserialization problem. Have you verified that the JSON is properly deserialized? Mostly the C# object requires to have a default constructor in order to be instatntiated by the deserializer. Your data types don't have one. But this are details that depend on your used library, which is not clear.

Comment: @BionicCode Yes, I have a default constructor for BuiltInCategoryName, I forgot to add it to the code snippet. I also added a default constructor to ParameterRow, but that's not the reason. It's still not displaying when restoring.

Comment: @BionicCode, I just confirmed and deserialization is working properly, however, the DisplayMemberPath is blank after restore.

Comment: It's a guessing game for me. You should show the minmal code that reproduces the issue. If it is only not working after deserialization, and you have verified that deserialization works without failure (e.g. the CategoryName values are also deserialized properly and the property is not empty??), then you should check if the source collection is properly initialized. But since other columns are displayed prperly I doubt that this is the case. I'm still not convinced that the deserialization has completed successfully. Please inspect thedeserialized items if the CategoryName property is valid.

Comment: @BionicCode I can confirm that CategoryName property is not null after deserialization and also the source collection is properly initialized. In fact, when I save the restored data, I can see that Category is indeed Walls despite nothing being displayed in the datagrid.

Comment: Good, thank you. The next please verify that you initialize your `BuiltInCategoryName` property which binds to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`. If you don't do this then the ComboBox will not have any selection and thereofre  not display any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved this issue was instead of using the `SelectedItemBinding` property I used `SelectedValueBinding`.

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding BicnList}" x:Key="bicnList"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DgNamingConventionRows}"
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bicnList}}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding BuiltInCategoryName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"/>
                 </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <!--............!-->
       </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
```